# Merging cells in multiple columns on multiple sheets

Tags: performance, vba, excel

This code merges cells in multiple columns on multiple sheets, and it's too slow.

I'm hoping for any help at all to speed this up. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get around the fact that the cells must be merged.

I broke up the for statements - it helped a bit, but it's still very, very slow.

Also, I turned off screenupdating, events, calculation, displaypagesbreaks, etc.; it didn't seem to help.

```
Function MergeCells()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ShName As String

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    PIS.Activate

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        Select Case ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            Case "Med Curr", "Med Ren", "Med RevRen", "Med Prop", "Med Renewal Alts A", "Med Renewal Alts B", _
                "Med Renewal Alts C", "Med Prop Other Markets 1A", "Med Prop Other Markets 1B", "Med Prop Other Markets 1C", _
                "Med Prop Other Markets 2A", "Med Prop Other Markets 2B", "Med Prop Other Markets 2C", _
                "Med Prop Other Markets 3A", "Med Prop Other Markets 3B", "Med Prop Other Markets 3C"
                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
                    ShName = ActiveSheet.Name
                MergeCellsx (ShName)
        End Select
    Next i

End Function

Function MergeCellsx(ShName)

    Dim RngB As Range
    Dim row As Integer

    With Sheets(ShName)
        For row = 6 To 12
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 14 To 18
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 20 To 22
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 24 To 25
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
        For row = 27 To 34
            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 5), .Cells(row, 6))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

            Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 8), .Cells(row, 9))
            RngB.Merge
            RngB.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        Next row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You should summarize what your code is supposed to do in your question title. Also give some more background in your question body. You might be interested to read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43264019/1188513) might help you with the *not able to get around the fact that the cells must be merged* part.

Comment: You've a lot of copied info `Set RngB = .Range(.Cells(row, 2), .Cells(row, 3))` that could become a its own `Sub MergeAndCenter(ByVal ws as worksheet, ByVal rw as Long, ByVal cl as Long)`. It would at least make future edits easier and your code quite a bit neater.

Comment: I have to ask... how about formatting as `Center Across Selection`?

Comment: @PeterT asks a good question - center across selection is pretty much always preferable to merging.

Comment: Also, if you turned off screenupdating, etc - why isn't it turned off in the code? Did you turn it back on?

Comment: Center across works beautifully, at a fraction of time compared to merge and center. Thank you very much PeterT and Raystafarian!!

Comment: Is `PIS` a sheet's name?

Answer (score 1):

Some notes -

#### Sub or Function

Functions should be used when something is *returned* and subs should be used when something *happens*. In this case they are actually both `Sub`s.

---

#### Naming

So I think `PIS` is the actual name of the sheet, not a variable. But, it's all uppercase and not very descriptive. In this case I would think it's a constant because
[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables, UPPER_CASE for constants and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

---

#### Variables

You did a good job declaring all of your variables, but it's always a good idea to turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

**Names** - names are cheap and characters are free. You can use this to your advantage by giving all of your variables descriptive names. For instance - `RngB` tells me nothing about what that range is supposed to be doing.

Integers - [integers are obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

---

#### Select Case

Why do you have a select case given you're basically using it like an `IF`? It looks pretty messy, to me. You could fix that up with a constant. Personally, I'd pull it out as its own function -

```
Private Function IsTargetSheet(ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean
    Const SHEET_NAMES As String = "Med Curr, Med Ren, Med RevRen, Med Prop, Med Renewal Alts A, Med Renewal Alts B, Med Renewal Alts C, Med Prop Other Markets 1A, Med Prop Other Markets 1B, Med Prop Other Markets 1C, Med Prop Other Markets 2A, Med Prop Other Markets 2B, Med Prop Other Markets 2C, Med Prop Other Markets A, Med Prop Other Markets 3B, Med Prop Other Markets 3C"
    If InStr(1, SHEET_NAMES, sheetName) > 0 Then
        IsTargetSheet = True
    Else: IsTargetSheet = False
End Function
```

And now you just need this in the main sub -

```
For i = 1 To sheetCount
    sheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    If IsTargetSheet(sheetName) Then MergeCellsx sheetName
Next i
```

---

#### MergeCellsx

In case you didn't know, a `Sub` can take an argument the same way as a function -

```
Sub MergeCells(ByVal sheetName as String)
```

I see you are targeting columns 2 and 3, 5 and 6, 8 and 9. When you have something like that, it might be better to put those number in a variable or constant so that if they change, you can just change the initial value of the variable. -

```
Const FIRST_NAME_COLUMN As Long = 2
Const SECOND_NAME_COLUMN As Long = 3
```

Now every time you type in the columns, you can use the constant which will tell you what the column is supposed to contain.

Also, in this instance, you would probably be better with a long `if` instead of 15 conditional loops. Maybe even the select case would belong here. When you see repeated code like that, it's an indication you can refactor it.